# How to get minecraft leather without cows or rabbits

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want some leather but i could not spot some cows or some rabbits

Answer (score 1):

You can get leather through the following ways (besides Rabbits and Cows)

- 0-2 Leather from killing Horses/Mules/Donkeys
- Foxes have a 20% chance to spawn holding Leather, and has a 8.5% drop chance (guaranteed drop on Bedrock Edition) when killed. Alternatively you can trade food to make it drop the leather without killing.
- 0.5%-1.2% chance to obtain when fishing.

Next update (1.16), you can:

> Barter with a [Piglin](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Piglin#Bartering) with a 9.43% chance to get 4-10 Leather per Gold Ingot.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure Llamas also have a slight chance to drop leather, and you can also loot dungeons and other structures for leather, although chances are you will find a cow/rabbit soon enough.